# Responsive 4 to 2 column website with images

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, multiple-columns

im trying to make responsive website with 4 columns when width is over 1000px and 2 columns if it is under 1000px.

![][1]

On the image you can see how it looks (1) when the display is over 1000px. (2) how it should look like after decreasing browser width under 1000px. And (3) shows how it is messed up when I add picture.

```css
#stred {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#img {
  width: 80%;
}
#center {
  text-align: center;
}
#container1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}
#col1 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#col2 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#col3 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#col4 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #stred {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #container1 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  #col1 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
  }
  #col2 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: yellow;
  }
  #col3 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: green;
  }
  #col4 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <div id="col1">
    <p id="center">Column 1</p>
    <div id="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="col2">
    <p id="center">Column 2</p>
    <br>text</div>
  <div id="col3">
    <p id="center">Column 3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="col4">
    <p id="center">Column 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to have columns with images like it is shows at second part of the image while using HTML and CSS only? If so, how?

Comment: Please try to clean up the language in the example picture you provided.

Comment: yeah ... i sorry about it, it is my childist side, just imagine ,,text,, instead of it, please :)

Comment: You can use (@media screen and) to define the sizes you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple way is to use `flex` and `min-width` or mediaqueries.

- example with min-width at 250px , gives a break point every 250px .

```css
#container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#container1 > div {
  min-width: 250px;
  flex: 1;
}
#container1 > div img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
#col1 {
  background: red;
}
#col2 {
  background: yellow;
}
#col3 {
  background: green;
}
#col4 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <div id="col1">
    <p id="center1">Column 1</p>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x150" />
  </div>
  <div id="col2">
    <p id="center2">Column 2</p>
    <br>text</div>
  <div id="col3">
    <p id="center3">Column 3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="col4">
    <p id="center4">Column 4</p>
  </div>
</div>`
```

- example with mediaquerie: 1 break point only

```css
#container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#container1 > div {
  width:25%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #container1 > div {
  width:50%;
}
  }
#container1 > div img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
#col1 {
  background: red;
}
#col2 {
  background: yellow;
}
#col3 {
  background: green;
}
#col4 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <div id="col1">
    <p id="center1">Column 1</p>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x150" />
  </div>
  <div id="col2">
    <p id="center2">Column 2</p>
    <br>text</div>
  <div id="col3">
    <p id="center3">Column 3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="col4">
    <p id="center4">Column 4</p>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: Thanks for help, not sure what this part of code does:
 #container1 > div {
  min-width: 250px;
  flex: 1;
}
#container1 > div img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
but this:
#container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
} 
saved my day, thank you :)

Comment: @LukášJirůšek flex:1 sprays evenly boxes, min-width make a box fall down next line when it reaches the min-width, so others grow untill, one more is too much and so on ..

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebp2eo24/)
GCyrillus provides you flex box, which I also prefer. It makes super easy to aline blocks and give them space. About the medias, you can check the fiddle here to see how it works.

```
@media screen and (max-width:1000px){
  div{
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
}
```